# ASPNET Core 2.1 Read/Stream FormCollection

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-core

I am dealing with big payloads for uploading images into a server so I had updated the classic `[HttpPost]` + `[FromBody]` to start using `FormCollection` and send the actual content in chunks. So far so good however to get it to work I had the following code:

```
            [HttpPost]
            [Authorize]
            [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
            public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync()
            {
                var form = await Request.ReadFormAsync();

                var myObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(form["data"]);

                for(var i = 0; i < form.Files.Count; ++i)
                {
                    myObject.Images[i].File = form.Files.ElementAt(i) as FormFile;
                }
                ...more stuff and return 201 if created otherwise 202
            }
```

my first question is to know whether the  ReadFormAsync is actually correct. I found that unless I put that in place, the stream of data starts being sent however the API also starts running the method and no data has actually arrived if that makes sense. I'm not sure if there is something out of the box that does that for me - something like an attribute or something (I'm looking for best practices here).

Then my second question is that I actually have to split my data between files (to fo to the form.Files section and the actual object which I'm serializing as Json in the UI. I'm not sure if that's also correct or whether it should be done in a different way.

I'm using an Angular 7 UI to perform the request:

```
        public post(formData: FormData): Promise<boolean> {
            const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': this.authService.getAuthorizationHeaderValue()
            });

            const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `${environment.apiBaseUrl}/myEndpoint/`, formData, {
                reportProgress: false,
                headers: headers
            });

            return new Promise<boolean>((r) => {
                this.http.request<boolean>(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
                    if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
                    r(event.body);
                }
            });
        });
     }
```

Any feedback is really appreciated

Comment: You're not streaming/chunking the upload at all. Awaiting `Request.ReadFormAsync();` is going to hold until the full payload is read into memory/disk, and then continue processing. In other words, absolutely no different than just accepting it as a param and using modelbinding, except now, you're having to handle the modelbinding part manually. To actually stream see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1#uploading-large-files-with-streaming. As you can see, it's *significantly* more complicated.

Comment: OK - I'll try that. Many thanks for pointing me out the right direction